# Angular 4 map certain JSON data to class and return observable

Tags: json, angular, typescript

So I am trying to learn some basic Angular by creating an application that fetches and displays the current weather of a location using OpenWeather API.

This is what I have in my code currently:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from './weather.service';    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [WeatherService]
})    
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Ng-Weather';
  cityName: string;
  weather: Weather;    
  constructor(private weather: WeatherService) { }    
  search() {
    this.weather.getWeatherbyName(this.cityName)
      .subscribe(res => this.weather = res);
    console.log(this.weather);
  }
}
```

weather.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Weather } from './weather';
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  APIurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  Appid = "xxx";
  weather: Weather;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getWeatherbyName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.append('appid', this.Appid);
    myParams.append('q', name);
    return this.http.get(this.APIurl , { search: myParams} )
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    this.weather.city = body.name;
    this.weather.description = body.weather[0].main;
    this.weather.temp = body.main.temp;
    console.log(this.weather);
  }
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

weather.ts:

```
export class Weather {
    city: String;
    description: String;
    temp: String;
}
```

So basically I am trying to map a JSON returned from OpenWeather API and get only some parts of the data and not the whole thing. The JSON returned is like following:

```
{  
    "coord":{  
        "lon":80.28,
        "lat":13.09
    },
    "weather":[  
        {  
            "id":802,
            "main":"Clouds",
            "description":"scattered clouds",
            "icon":"03n"
        }
    ],
    "base":"stations",
    "main":{  
        "temp":303.15,
        "pressure":1008,
        "humidity":79,
        "temp_min":303.15,
        "temp_max":303.15
    },
    "visibility":6000,
    "wind":{  
        "speed":3.1,
        "deg":210
    },
    "clouds":{  
        "all":40
    },
    "dt":1504805400,
    "sys":{  
        "type":1,
        "id":7834,
        "message":0.0017,
        "country":"IN",
        "sunrise":1504744074,
        "sunset":1504788314
    },
    "id":1264527,
    "name":"Chennai",
    "cod":200
}
```

When the above code is executed, I get this error:

```
weather.service.ts:32 Cannot set property 'city' of undefined
```

Also how do I return an observable of type Weather and return that variable weather and catch it on the app.component.ts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Typescript casting JSON response as object model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022440/angular-typescript-casting-json-response-as-object-model-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not creating an instance of the weather object before assigning its properties. You can do that explicitly like this:

```
this.weather = new Weather();
this.weather.city = body.name;
this.weather.description = body.weather[0].main;
this.weather.temp = body.main.temp;
console.log(this.weather);
```

OR

You can do something like this:

```
this.weather = { 
                 city: body.name,
                 description: body.weather[0].main,
                 temp: body.main.temp
               }
console.log(this.weather);
```

And to answer the second part of your question, you should be able to do this:

```
  getWeatherbyName(name: string): Observable<Weather> {
      // your other code
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    // your other code
    return this.weather;
  }
```

And to answer the third part of your question ... Observables are asynchronous. This means that they do not immediately return a value. Rather they provide for definition of a callback function that is executed when the data is returned. That means that the data is **undefined** until the data is returned and the callback function is executed.

So if you want to access the returned data in your code, you need to do in *WITHIN* the callback function. Like this:

```
  search() {
    this.weather.getWeatherbyName(this.cityName)
      .subscribe(res => {
             this.weather = res;
             console.log(this.weather);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me very much! Just wondering if you can help me catch in the component as well. I have this in my component: `search() {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherbyName(this.cityName)
      .subscribe(res => this.weather = res);
    console.log(this.weather);
  }` and I get an undefined when printing to console.

Comment: Can you add this to your question because the code does not format well in the comments section.

Comment: thanks! helped me understand more with the explanations rather than just the answer.