# Typescript Extended Interface Casting - Missing Properties/Methods

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript interface that I am trying to extend, but at run time my properties and methods are missing. Could someone have a look and see if there is something I'm doing completely wrong?

**Inherited Interface generated from TypeLite**

```
declare module ModelsShared {
    interface AddressModel {
        Country: ModelsSupportingData.SupportingDataModel;
        County: string;
        Line1: string;
        Line2: string;
        Line3: string;
        Postcode: string;
        Town: string;
    }
}
```

As I can't change these interfaces as they are automatically re-generated, I extended it with my own interface:

```
interface IAddressModel extends ModelsShared.AddressModel {
  FlatString: string;
  asFlatString() : string;
}
```

And then implemented that interface with an exported class:

```
    export class AddressModel implements IAddressModel {
      public Country: ModelsSupportingData.SupportingDataModel;
      public County: string;
      public Line1: string;
      public Line2: string;
      public Line3: string;
      public Postcode: string;
      public Town: string;
      public FlatString : string;

      public asFlatString = (): string => {         
        return "A nice formatted address";
      }
   }
```

However, even on casting the address as my interface, such as:

```
let address: IAddressModel = (user.Address as IAddressModel);
```

And although VS is happy, I do not get the property or method at run-time, I just undefined.

Comment: `as IAddressModel` **does not** do any casting or conversion. It's an assertion; you're telling the compiler *you know* it will be that type. In this case, it seems you're wrong. Presumably you're getting JSON somewhere; you need to *explicitly* deserialise that into the appropriate class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Typescript casting JSON response as object model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022440/angular-typescript-casting-json-response-as-object-model-not-working)

Comment: You did not present any initialization code for `user` and `user.Address` in your code. In case you did not instantiate `user.Address` you should not expect it to be set, hence it will be `undefined`