# Angular HttpClient is not returning quite the objects I expect

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say I have

```
class Foo {
    bar: string;

    public doSomething() {}

}
```

In my service I'm getting array of those from a server:

```
this.http.get<Foo[]>(...)
```

This works, I'm getting all the expected values. BUT when I take one of the objects I got and try to invoke doSomething() on it, I get an error saying that foo (which is of type Foo) doesn't have method doSomething().

It appears that while http.get correctly parsed JSON and assigned all the properties of my objects, it didn't bother with setting up proper prototypes for them, so essentially they are Foos in name only, they are missing all the methods of Foo.

Is that normal or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: The thing about working with external data is, you will get an object created by deserialized data, then cast into the type that you chose. It's not the real instance of that type, hence knows nothing about the functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Typescript casting JSON response as object model not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022440/angular-typescript-casting-json-response-as-object-model-not-working)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Effectively. In the end, you're just parsing JSON, and the result of parsing JSON are just plain JavaScript objects, never custom classes. `this.http.get<Foo[]>` is just a hint for the compiler, but the generic parameter does not really do anything. It doesn't convert one object in another, not does it give them types.

As an advice, you should never use classes when typecasting the result of calls to services or getting objects from `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` and such. You should use interfaces instead, without methods.

However, it is possible to achieve what you want, if you really need your objects to be of class `Foo` and have the `doSomething` method:

```
this.http.get<Foo[]>(...).do(items => items.forEach(item => Object.setPrototypeOf(item, Foo.prototype)));
```

This will give every object the correcto prototype. However, this has a performance penalty, as changing the prototype of created objects messes with browser optimization, so do it under your own risk.

Another option would be to give `Foo` a constructor:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(item: Foo) {
        Object.assign(this, item);
    }

    bar: string;

    public doSomething() {}
}
```

Now:

```
this.http.get<Foo[]>(...).pipe(map(items => items.map(item => new Foo(item)))).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Note that now, the `do` method mentioned here would be replaces with `pipe` and `tap` like this : this.http.get<Foo[]>(...).pipe(tap(items => items.forEach(item => Object.setPrototypeOf(item, Foo.prototype))));

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by inheritance like this:

```
this.http.get<Foo>(...)
    .pipe(Foo.serializeResponseMap());
```

class definition:

```
export class Foo extends SerializableMap {
    static instanceType = Foo;

    constructor() { super(); }

    bar: string;

    public doSomething() {}
}


class SerializableMap {
  static instanceType: any;

  static serializeResponseMap(): any {
    const createInstance = (r) => {
      return Object.assign(new this.instanceType(), r);
    };

    return map((respValue: any) => {
      if (Array.isArray(respValue)) {
        return respValue.map(r => createInstance(r));
      }
      return createInstance(respValue);
    });
  }
}
```