# Angular 5, HttpClient won't use the constructor of class

Tags: angular, constructor, observable, httpclient, angular5

I have a service and a component.

some.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { SomeClass } from '../model/some.class';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData(): Observable<SomeClass[]> {
        let url = 'someUrlEndpoint';
        let results = this.http.get<SomeClass[]>(url);
        return results;
    }

}
```

---

some.component.ts

```
import { SomeService } from './service/some.service';

import { SomeClass } from './model/some.class';

export class SomeComponent {

    someClass: SomeClass[];

    constructor(private someService: SomeService)

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData()
    }

    getData() {
        this.someService.getData()
          .subscribe(res => this.someClass = res);
    }
}
```

---

some.class.ts

```
export class SomeClass {
    title: string;
    status: string;
    numberOfPersons: number;
    persons: string;
    ...

    constructor(json: any = "") {
        this.title = json.title;
        this.status = getStatus(json.status);
        this.numberOfPersons = getNumberOfPersons(json.persons);
        this.persons = json.persons;
        ...
    }

    getStatus(value: number) {
        let status = StatusCase.ongoing;
        if(value == 1) {status = StatusCase.done}
        if(value == 2) {status = StatusCase.completeWithDeviations}
        if(value == 3) {status = StatusCase.aborted}
        return status;
    }

    getPersons(value: string) {
        let persons = 0;
        get persons splitted by comma, count it up and return
        return persons;
    }
}

export enum StatusCase {
    ongoing = "Ongoing";
    aborted = "Aborted";
    completeWithDeviations = "Complete with deviations";
    done = "Done";
}
```

I am able to get the data, but not in the way I want.

Now, since the httpClient doesn't return an instance of the SomeClass, it will not go through the constructor, and the application will not get the correct data that it needs.
So where does 'new SomeClass(data)' fit in? Is it at all possible to do in the way that httpClient is constructed? Or must I get the untyped data (json) and do a for loop to populate the someClass: SomeClass[] in the traditional way?

Or is there another smarter way to populate calculated properties?
Use interceptors to manipulate data in the response? It seems though that interceptors on the response is just for errors.

Comment: No, of course it doesn't. `.get<SomeClass[]>` is just a hint so that the compiler can help you with response processing; TypeScript *doesn't exist a runtime*, only at compile time, so it cannot do any validation, casting or conversion. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50165067/3001761.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. So the json way then. And the generic way when only interfaces is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`.get<SomeClass[]>` Doesn't do anything. It only is useful during development. You can run a map operator and return an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) to map the HTTP response plain javascript into your class objects simply enough:

```
// assuming that your json response from the http call is an array
const obs: Observable<SomeClass[]> = this.http.get(url).map(res => 
   plainToClass(SomeClass, res));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

Not there is not a way to do it. Explanation below, or just skip to solution to this problem, though you outlined it pretty decent in your question.

---

## Long Answer

When you use a generic here `.get<SomeClass[]>()` you are offering more information to typescript to help with code correctness at transpile time (static + strong typing). Remember Typescript is just a superset of JS, so when runtime happens there is no way of knowing really that what you have there is a class.. because classes themselves in js are just syntactical sugar over the prototype model.

So what is still happening under the hood is `JSON.parse(jsonStr)`.. Because of duck typing this object will (if your class matches the incoming JSON correctly) be able to fit the bill as it were. If you want to instantiate a class you will have to do this yourself.

---

## Solution

### Simple way where we can just spread the keys to an instance

```
this.http.get<SomeClass[]>(url)
    .pipe( 
        map( someClasses => 
            someClasses.map( someClass => Object.assign(new SomeClass(), { ...someClass } ) 
        ) 
    )
    .subscribe( someClasses => results = someClasses);
```

### Or constructor route.. P.S You don't need to use `any` in your constructor.

```
export class SomeClass {
    constructor(someClass: SomeClass) {
        this.title = someClass.title;
        this.status = this.getStatus(someClass.status);
        //...
    }

    getStatus(value: number) {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
this.http.get<SomeClass[]>(url)
    .pipe( 
        map( someClasses => 
            someClasses.map( someClass => new SomeClass(someClass) ) 
        ) 
    )
    .subscribe( someClasses => results = someClasses);
```